# Youtube fragment failed show video with error "Giving up device auth after 5 tries"

Tags: android, youtube-api

I use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment in my project:

```
 fragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    initialize();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id. video_plugin_details_youtube_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

And initialize method:

```
public void initialize() {
    fragment.initialize(YouTubeApi.YOUTUBE_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                player = youTubePlayer;
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(YouTubeUtils.getVideoId(currentItem.getUrl()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            System.out.print("asd");
        }
    });
}
```

After running callback method onInitializationSuccess called and code looks like works fine, but video not playing. On device apears message in youtube fragment:
There was a problem while playing.

In logcat I found only one error message

```
08-15 10:58:20.512 160-699/? W/FrameworkListener: Handler 'getaddrinfo' error (Connection reset by peer)
08-15 10:58:20.512 15855-18598/com.google.android.youtube.player D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: www.googleapis.com NO result from proxy
08-15 10:58:20.512 15855-18598/com.google.android.youtube.player I/System.out: [CDS][DNS]Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 10:58:20.513 15855-18598/com.google.android.youtube.player E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Giving up device auth after 5 tries
```

Please help me to fix it?

Comment: Can you verify that 1) the device has internet access and 2) you've told the YouTube video player to play a valid video?

Comment: @matthewayne  , Yes device has internet access. This code work fine on Samsung Galaxt S3 (4.3), Samsung SM-T230 (4.4.2) and NEXUS 5 (6.0).
But on THL 5000 (4.4.2 KOT49H) ,and probably, with some other devices, youtube failed with error

Comment: Do the devices where the YouTube error occurred have the YouTube app installed?  The YouTube app needs to be installed for the YouTube Android fragment player to work.

Comment: Yes. Youtube app installed